# Rails ActionMailer::Base attach txt file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does anybody know, how can I attach text file (test.txt) on email in RoR ?

For example, I have a code:

```
def send
  attachments['test.txt'] = <Some content>
  mail to: examepl@example.com,
       subject: 'Test attach txt file'
end
```

There are a lot of email clients show this file just as text, not as attachment. May be, I should set some headers or something else ?

Comment: The question could do better with a list of clients you have confirmed to do that. And a screenshot of at least one case.

Comment: @D-side for example, AirMail 2: http://take.ms/EF6aC

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to assign file content after read from a path and it worked for me and sending email as an attachment, did you try something like this ?

```
attachments['test.txt'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/test.txt")
```

Can you tell a bit more about your problem?

Comment: So, I have a some text, and I want send the text as attachment (as test.txt), I tried to create a file, then attachments['test.txt'] = File.read("test.txt"), but it didn't help me. Thunderbird and AirMail 2 didn't attach the file, just show as simple text.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach do as follows:

`attachment['test.txt'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/test.txt")`

See this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#complete-list-of-action-mailer-methods

Comment: In this case thunderbird and AirMail 2 didn't attach the file, just show as simple text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get text data from file then you need to read file like below.

```
file = open(file.url).read
attachments["file.txt"] = { :data => file }
```

If you have data in a string then

```
attachments["file.txt"] = { :data => data_string }
```